# how to register all classes in assembly with Castle Windsor in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor, orchardcms

I'm starting with ASP.NET MVC 3 and modules.

Like the Orchard CMS modules, I want to have modules as assemblies with Razor pages (inside/outside the DLL). I followed [Mika Kolari's tutorial](http://mikakolari.fi/2011/02/aspnetmvc-3-plugin-architecture-with-embedded-razor-views/), but I don't know how to include all the classes from the assembly namespace in the core project with Castle Windsor.

I'm able to load Controller from the assembly, but not Model for the view. I get missing namespace error.

In Application_start() I have:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dll.FullName);
//different from Mika's
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssembly(assembly)
                           .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Model")));
```

and Settings.cshtml file invoking the error:

```
@{
Layout = ";~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
var viewModel = Model as Crash.PageRating.SettingsViewModel; //error missing namespace Crash.PageRating
}
```

Mika says that @model does not work for him either.

Here is my [solution](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9865839/Crash.zip)

Thanks for help!

Comment: why do you want to register a viewmodel in an IoC container?

Comment: I want to use the model from the module assembly in the Razor View. I thought I have to do it through IoC registration.

Comment: which turned to be a totally diferrent question.